# proving Ramanujan´s integral formula

Tags: calculus, integration

in a ramanujan´s study about the integrtal $$\int_0^x \frac{arctan(t)}{t}\,dt=\omega(x) \qquad (1)$$
He said that changing t into 1/t in (1), he obtain that
 $$\omega(x)-\omega(1/x)=\frac{\pi\cdot\log(x)}{2} \qquad (2)$$
and that this results can be easly proven by differentianting both side with respect to x,and that (2) is provided that the real part of x is positive.
I tried to use this identity
$\arctan(y)+arctan(1/y) =\frac{\pi}{2}$

for y positive or cero, but i can´t use it.
has anyone discovered a way to prove (2)?If so, how do you prove it?
Here's the original paper if someone want to see it https://www.imsc.res.in/~rao/ramanujan/collectedindex.html

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition on using the arctangent identity$$\arctan x+\arctan\left(\frac 1x\right)=\frac {\pi}2$$
is correct. Call the integral $\mathfrak{I}$ and realize that$$\begin{align*}\mathfrak I & =\omega(x)-\omega\left(\frac 1x\right)\\ & =\int\limits_{1/x}^x\mathrm dt\,\frac {\arctan t}t\end{align*}$$
Make a reciprocal transformation $t\mapsto\tfrac 1t$ to get that$$\mathfrak I=\int\limits_{1/x}^x\mathrm dt\,\frac {\arctan t}t=\int\limits_{1/x}^x\mathrm dt\,\frac {\arctan\left(\frac 1t\right)}t$$Averaging the two expressions gives$$\begin{align*}\mathfrak I & =\frac 12\int\limits_{1/x}^x\mathrm dt\,\frac 1t\left[\arctan t+\arctan\left(\frac 1t\right)\right]\\ & =\frac {\pi}4\log t\,\Biggr\rvert_{1/x}^x\\ & =\frac {\pi}2\log x\end{align*}$$

Comment: sorry for the question but, what do you mean with "reciprocal transfomation"?could you explain this please?sorry for this english

Comment: @Blas Casazza  Change of variable $y=\dfrac{1}{t}$

Comment: @BlasCasazza What I did was make the substitution $u=\frac 1t$, then replaced $u$ with $t$. That’s what I meant by $t\mapsto\tfrac 1t$.